# How big does a circular geofence need to be for the curvature of the earth to matter?

Tags: distance, geometry, spherical-geometry, gis-principle, geofencing

I'm working on adding geofences to a mobile application. I know the proper way of calculating distance between two points on a sphere is using the [great-circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) or [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula. I don't know if using those formulas are needed for relatively small scale applications. This leads to my question.

#### At what point does the distance given by a great-circle calculation diverge significantly from a planar calculation?

---

- For the purposes of this discussion assume greater than 5% error is significant.
- The geofence is simply a center point and a radius. If the point is within the radius, by distance, it is considered within the boundaries of the fence.
- I am not sure if it matters, but I'm just worried about circular geofences at this time with a user defined radius between 50 and 200 meters.

Comment: It's not the radius of the circle that matters so much as the number of vertices used to define it.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175393/circle-area-calculation-in-qgis-is-inaccurate/175394#175394

Comment: @Vince I'm confused about "vertices" for a circular geofence. There wouldn't be vertices persay to define it. Just a center point and a radius. If the distance from the center point is less than or equal to the radius it would be within the fence.

Comment: No, in the real world, circles are represented as polygons. The resulting figure can be indexed, improving the performance of the 'inside' test over a full table scan distance calculation (avoiding a square root calculation).

Comment: @Vince Regardless of how programmers optimize/implement the inside problem there should be a mathematical solution that describes the divergence between a planar solution and an Earth sized sphere. All that being said I very well might not understand the point you're driving at. If you can post an answer that explains the problem in more domain appropriate terms and gives a superior solution that I can understand I'll certainly up-vote it and quite possibly accept it. As it stands I'm incapable of understanding how `circles are always polygons` meaningfully answers my question.

Comment: If we're talking about the distance between two points, we could put them on a circle instead of a sphere, which reduces the complexity of the problem. Is you question then basically: at what point does the chord length deviate from the arc length by 5% given two points on a circle? If that's the case, the answer is about 6993 km, which is way more than 200 m. I would put this and the explanation as an answer, but I want to make sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: @user55937 It has been a long time since I took geometry, but that doesn't feel like it would accurately reflect the question. My mental picture could be wrong, but I visualize the problem like a sphere with planar circle sitting on top like a hat with the contact point being the origin location. Then there would be another point on the sphere. A great circle calculation would give the accurate distance to that other point. A planar circle calculation would give a false distance to that other point. Your plan feels wrong because the planar calculation (cord) is inside the earth not above.

Comment: The answer I was thinking of and the answer you're looking for are related by a cos(theta) (interior angle between the two points), so they're going to be virtually the same for the very small angles you'd be considering. But you're right that I did misunderstand your question.

Comment: I have answered versions of this question in many places on this site, including http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25494 (discussing the error in using a sphere instead of an ellipsoid), http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7293 (errors in a Mercator projection), http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1351 (discussion of Equidistant projections), http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155828 (a **direct answer to this question** in terms of local Cartesian coordinates), http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5068 (calculating distance distortions in any projection),

Comment: (continued) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107992 (another analysis of errors in local distance calculations), and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58653 (**another direct answer** involving an analysis of the entire sphere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/664/whuber) gave a [wonderful answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58668/67367) that addresses the central folly of this idea. While he doesn't say this directly most people, like me, initially overlook two interrelated factors.

1. **Longitude converges at the poles.** That means that the distance between 0<sup>o</sup> longitude and 1<sup>o</sup> longitude is different when measuring along the equator and the 80<sup>th</sup> parallel.
2. Planar coordinate systems **rely on a constant rate of change** in both the x and y directions no matter where you are located. In a graph moving one step to the right is always the same distance irregardless of whether I'm at the origin or 80 steps above/below the origin.

As you can see the longitude breaks this assumption and therefore it will produce variably poor results. It is not merely a question of x distance traveled equates to y error, because the scale/magnitude varies depending on where the points are on the globe.

As you can see even though it is appealing to view the GPS coordinate system as a planar graph with a bounding box, **the planar graph analogy doesn't work because of how longitude is structured**. As such a methodology that would work on a planar graph is wholly inappropriate for a problem utilizing latitude and longitude.

To play on an analogy that whuber made in his answer, treating GPS coordinates like points on a planar graph is like trying to [square the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle). Many people have tried, but they were inevitably disappointed.